GAWK expanding 1 liner for an awk script
I have a one liner I want to expand into a script that will take a range of regexp and sum $3  printing list consisting of the matched regexp followed by a summed amount of  $3.
One liner
    awk -F "|" '$2 ~ /BYRON PHARMACY/ {sum += $3} END {print "BYRON PHARMACY" sum}' > data_file`

Which produces
    BYRON PHARMACY 24.95
(expected result)
from this file:
   18-06-2024 | " BYRON PHARMACY        BYRON                Ref#973043" | 24.95
   16-06-2024 | " PAYPAL *MITCH DOWD    Sydney               Ref#820999" | 79.90
   16-06-2024 | " Lotus Wholefoods      Melbourne            Ref#229370" | 7.79
   15-06-2024 | " SMP*Sweet Melbourne   Melbourne 03AU       Ref#047483" | 6.57
   15-06-2024 | " AMAZON AU             SYDNEY SOUTH         Ref#991691" | 49.98
   15-06-2024 | " SQ *L BOLEYN          Melbourne            Ref#495339" | 40.00
   14-06-2024 | " AMZNPRIMEAU MEMBERSHI SYDNEY SOUTH         Ref#370813" | 9.99
   14-06-2024 | " AMAZON MARKETPLACE    AU SYDNEY SOUTH      Ref#360527" | 41.32
   13-06-2024 | " HEARTHFIRE            BYRON                Ref#462520" | 4.00
   13-06-2024 | " POST BYRON            LPO  BYRON           Ref#462519" | 10.90
   12-06-2024 | " BYRON IGA             BYRON                Ref#820468" | 4.90
   12-06-2024 | "Int Tran Fee           - PAYPAL *WANCHER SG Ref#906626" | 10.94
   12-06-2024 | " PAYPAL *WANCHER       4029357733 SG        Ref#006626" | 364.50
   21-05-2024 | " AGL Sales Pty Ltd                          Rec#336551" | 405.59

I want to expand this into an awk script that produces as an example the following result from the above file:
    BYRON PHARMACY 24.95
    AMAZON AU 49.98
    BYRON IGA 4.90
    AGL 405.59

I successfully created a script to do the same job as the one liner . How do I modify the script so it accepts multiple regexps, matches each one to a record and sums the corresponding  $3  and prints it out next to the matched regexp as per my example . This is a sample of the file, the original is 500 lines long.
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "|"
    sum = 0
}

$2 ~ /BYRON IGA/ {sum += $3}

END {
    print "BYRON IGA", sum
}

Original file example posted to retain relevance to  some answers:
    18-06-2024 | " blue   Sometown Ref#973043" | 24.95
    16-06-2024 | " green  Sometown Ref#820999" | 79.90
    16-06-2024 | " orange Sometown Ref#229370" | 7.79
    15-06-2024 | " blue   Sometown Ref#047483" | 6.57
    15-06-2024 | " yellow Sometown Ref#495339" | 40.00
    14-06-2024 | " orange Sometown Ref#370813" | 9.99
    14-06-2024 | " red    Sometown Ref#360527" | 41.32
    13-06-2024 | " blue   Sometown Ref#462520" | 4.00


Do you really need to look for regex, or are you actually just looking for substrings? Can a line match multiple regex (eg. a line containing yellow-green)? Do you want to print the regex (eg gr[ae]y) as the output label, or the match (eg. gray), or a fixed string (eg. ash-coloured)?

Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Please be warned that you might get undesired behavior if Sometown name contain color inside, e.g. Breda (Kingdom of Netherlands) has red inside.

Replace each Sometown with truly representative values on each input line so we can help you.

Edit after a major change in the question. Answer to the previous question at the end.
Let us assume that the various patterns to search for are real regular expressions stored in a file (regex.txt), one per line. You can try:
$ cat regex.txt
BYRON PHARMACY
AMAZON AU
BYRON IGA
AGL
$ awk -F '|' 'NR == FNR {re[$0]; next}
  {for(r in re) if($2 ~ r) sum[r] += $3}
  END {for(r in sum) print r, sum[r]}' regex.txt data.txt
AGL 405.59
AMAZON AU 49.98
BYRON IGA 4.9
BYRON PHARMACY 24.95

If you want to also print regular expressions that have not been matched (with an empty sum):
$ cat regex.txt
FOOBAR.*BARFOO
BYRON PHARMACY
AMAZON AU
BYRON IGA
AGL
$ awk -F '|' 'NR == FNR {re[$0]; next}
  {for(r in re) if($2 ~ r) sum[r] += $3}
  END {for(r in re) print r, sum[r]}' regex.txt data.txt
AGL 405.59
AMAZON AU 49.98
BYRON IGA 4.9
BYRON PHARMACY 24.95
FOOBAR.*BARFOO

Old answer with color names considered as strings:
If your input is always formatted as you show, with the color name as 4th word, and you want to print the sum for all colors:
$ awk '{sum[$4] += $NF}
  END {for(color in sum) print color, sum[color]}' data.txt
orange 17.78
red 41.32
yellow 40
green 79.9
blue 35.52

If you want to compute and print the sum only for some colors:
$ awk -v c='red green blue rainbow' '
  BEGIN {split(c, tmp); for(i in tmp) colors[tmp[i]]}
  $4 in colors {sum[$4] += $NF}
  END {for(color in sum) print color, sum[color]}' data.txt
red 41.32
blue 35.52
green 79.9

Note: colors with no entry in the input will be skipped in the output (like rainbow above). If you prefer to print them with an empty string as sum replace for(color in sum) with for(color in colors).
If you have all the strings to search for in a text file (colors.txt), one color per line:
$ cat colors.txt
red
green
blue
rainbow
$ awk 'FNR == NR {colors[$0]; next}
  $4 in colors {sum[$4] += $NF}
  END {for(color in sum) print color, sum[color]}' colors.txt data.txt
red 41.32
green 79.9
blue 35.52


FWIW I'd use END{for(color in colors) print color, sum[color]+0} to get a zero for each color that's not found. I'd also suggest the OP might want to add {colors[$4]} mid-script so the output contains all colors requested and found.

It depends a bit on exactly what you really want. If you want sums for all the colors, @Renaud has given a solid answer. If you want only the sums for some specific patterns, I'd probably do something on this order:
BEGIN {
    FS="|"
    colors = "blue,red,yellow,green";    # patterns to count, separated by commas
    split(colors, patterns, ",");
}

    { for (i in patterns) if (match($2, patterns[i])) { sum[i] += $3; } }

END {
    printf("\nSummary\n");
    for (i in sum) printf("%10s: %4.2f\n", patterns[i], sum[i]);
}

If you're dealing with a huge number of patterns, you might want to put them into a separate file, and read them from the file when you start, instead of putting them all into a string, and splitting the string to get an array of patterns.
Assuming a file named patterns.txt with one pattern per line, you could read its contents into patterns with code like this:
while (getline(foo) < "patterns.txt" > 0)
    patterns[++i] = $0;

The while line may be a bit confusing. The < does file redirection, about like in a shell script. But the > is a greater than sign, checking that the result of the read was greater than 0 (to detect the end of file).
It's probably also preferable to use the default field splitting, where the color name would be $4 and the value $8. This will prevent the contents of other parts of the data (Sometown, Ref#) from being interpreted as part of the pattern.

this looks the most suitable for my purposes. I have a lot of patterns, how do read them in in the BEGIN block ?

That would fail given various contents of the input, e.g. if a Sometown was actually Bredford


modify the script

If you have just few colors (blue, red, yellow, green) AND etched in stone you might simply add pattern-action pair for each and adjust print in END following way
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "|"
}

$2 ~ /blue/ {blue += $3}
$2 ~ /red/ {red += $3}
$2 ~ /yellow/ {yellow += $3}
$2 ~ /green/ {green += $3}

END {
    print "blue " blue "\nred " red "\nyellow " yellow "\ngreen " green
}

Observe that there is no need to set each counter to 0, as GNU AWK assumes it is 0 if it does not exist. Keep in mind this will ignore all colors which are not given. Note that I use spaces rather than ,s in print which are concatenations and \n denoting newlines. You might use printf rather than print, if you need more precise control over output.

Here is a Ruby that parses that format and groups the sums by the first alpha label in the second column:
ruby -e '
sums=Hash.new(0)
$<.map{|line| line.rstrip.split(/[ \t]*\|[ \t]*/)}.
    each{|row| sums[row[1][/[a-z]+/]]+=row[2].to_f}

c1=sums.max_by{|k,v| k.length}[0].length
sums.sort_by{|k,v| k}.map{|k,v| printf "%-*s %.2f\n", c1, k, v}
' file

Prints:
blue   35.52
green  79.90
orange 17.78
red    41.32
yellow 40.00

If you want to filter by specific labels (and sort into the order listed in the filter array):
ruby -e '
sums=Hash.new(0)
filter=["blue","red","yellow","green"]
$<.map{|line| line.rstrip.split(/[ \t]*\|[ \t]*/)}.
    each{|row| key=row[1][/[a-z]+/]; sums[key]+=row[2].to_f if filter.include? key } 

c1=sums.max_by{|k,v| k.length}[0].length
sums.sort_by{|k,v| filter.index(k)}.map{|k,v| printf "%-*s %.2f\n", c1, k, v}
' file

Prints:
blue   35.52
red    41.32
yellow 40.00
green  79.90

